# Spring Social Facebook: Get Facebook Post Image

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Currently, I'm using `posts.get(i).getPicture()` but this returns an image as a url which is very small in size.
How do I get this in a bigger size?
The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135087/spring-social-facebook-how-to-get-big-photo-from-post) but no solution :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27006154/757508

Comment: @luschn I do not want to use the GraphAPI. That question does not answer how to get a larger image in Spring for a specific post.

Comment: @Gokul1794 I want the same as you too, but I think there is no way with spring social.